# Sublime Text 2 when trying to change settings

Tags: sublimetext2

i tried to change some of settings in sublime text 2 from Preferences >> Settings - Default | adding a new settings from Settings - User, when i tried to change a value and save it a message appearing to me and its content is  ## Error typing to parse settings: Expected value in Packages/U.sser/Preferences.sublime-settings:4:1 ##

Comment: Let's see what you're trying to add...

Comment: To be more clear: please [edit] your question and paste in an **exact** copy of your current Settings-User file. Use the code format button in the edit view to make sure it looks like code in the preview down below.

Answer (score 0):

One of the settings you're trying to add in the User settings file is missing a value.

The User settings file should be in the format:

```
{
    "settingName": "textValue",
    "anotherSetting": numberValue
}
```

etc

If one of the values is missing you get that error.

Comment: actually, your example is incorrect as well, and won't parse. The last line can't have a comma `,` after it.

Comment: @MattDMo You're quite right. Parses in v3, not v2. Updated my answer.